# Testing Sencha-Cmd using Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, extjs4, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I have found several links to test Sencha-cmd app but none of them is working for me. 
[Jasmine with Extjs For Unit Tetsing](http://billhodges.me/technical/11-setting-up-jasmine-with-extjs-for-unit-testing?showall=&start=2) 
[Step Guide for Unit Testing ExtJS Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662832/Step-by-Step-Guide-for-Unit-Testing-ExtJS-Applicat)
But none of them is working. Is there any good workinf example for Sencha-Cmd application. 
Kindly help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Sencha CMD application"? Sencha CMD is a build tool. Did you mean "ExtJS application"?

Comment: Sorry for wrong word, yeah I meant Extjs application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently Setup Jasmine for testing my App using this tutorial [Unit and Regression Test Automation of Sencha applications](http://blogs.walkingtree.in/2013/04/09/unit-and-regression-test-automation-of-sencha-applications/) and it works perfectly fine. 
It mostly overlaps with your given links and It will definitely work.
You have to change default directory structure of ExtJS application but that should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Sorry, I forgot to accept it before. 
Thank you very much.